# Creating a new Set everytime a method is called

Tags: java

I have a map that should contain relations from an integer a to an integer b. Integer b should be in a Set. Relations from integer a to integer b can be added using the add method. To create such a relation, I have to create a new Set (to contain b) everytime the add method is called. How should I do this? I think I know how to do this with arrays since they support names containing variables, but sets don't.

```
public class intRelImplementation extends intRel {

    protected final Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> connection;

    public intRelImplementation (final int n) {
        super(n);
        connection = new HashMap<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void add(int a, int b) {
    // I have to create a new Set everytime the Add method is called. 
    // The Set should contain the Integer b, and this set should then be 
    // placed into the Map: Map<a, Set<b>>.
        Set<Integer> setInMap = new HashSet<>(); //not correct obviously
        Set setInMap2 = new HashSet(setInMap);
    }
```

Comment: What are the lines in `add` supposed to be doing? Are you trying to add a key/value pair into your multi-valued map?

Comment: @khelwood If by multi-valued map you mean a map containing multiple mappings, then yes. For example, valid commands could be add(4, 5) and add(7,8) afterwards. The map should then contain a mapping from the integer 4 to a set containing the integer 5, and a mapping from the integer 7 to a set containing the integer 8.

Comment: OK, but if you do `add(4,5)` and then `add(4,6)`, what do you expect then?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you are looking into fetching set from map using `a` as key, if nothing is there , create new set , add `b` and put the pair in map. If some set is already there with that key, get that set , add your b in that set, and replace the original set from your map .

Comment: @Jimmy Yes that is correct.

Comment: @khelwood then I would have to add 6 to the set which already contained 5. Anyway the main focus of my problem is creating a new set everytime the add method is called.

Comment: You have working answers below from multiple users. Glad I could help clarify the question.

Comment: What do you mean "The main focus of my problem is creating a new set every time"? You just said you _wouldn't_ create a new set in the case I asked about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you call `add(4,5)` and then `add(4,6)`.
If the result is that your map now contains `4 -> {5,6}` (that is, the key `4` links to a set containing `5` and `6`), then what you are making is a multi-valued map.

A way to add into a multi-valued map is something like this:

```
public void add(int a, int b) {
    Set<Integer> values = connection.get(a);
    if (values==null) {
        values = new HashSet<Integer>();
        connection.put(a, values);
    }
    values.add(b);
}
```

That is, get the set associated with the key `a`.
If there isn't one, create one and add it to the map.
Add your value `b` to the set.

Answer (score 3):

Just add a new `Set`, if there isn't already a mapping for `a` in the `Map` and then add the value to the `Set` in the `Map` (whether it was just added or previously in the map):

```
connection.computeIfAbsent(a, k -> new HashSet<Integer>()).add(b);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're looking for

```
public class intRelImplementation extends intRel {

    protected final Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> connection;

    public intRelImplementation (final int n) {
        super(n);
        connection = new HashMap<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void add(int key, int val) {
        if(!connection.containsKey(key)){
            connection.put(key, new HashSet<>());    
        }            
        connection.get(key).add(val);
    }
    ...
}
```

`!connection.containsKey(key)` will check if the `HashMap` contains the key mapping. If it doesnt, it will add an mapped entry for `{key, HashSet}` where `HashSet` is an empty `HashSet<Integer>`

`connection.get(key)` will return the `HashSet<Integer>` associated to the key in the HashMap.

`.add(val)` will now add the value to the `HashSet<Integer>`

This guarantees that a hashset is created if the key doesnt exist, and then it adds the value to the set owned by the key

Comment: You are using 3 lookups in case there is no mapping for the value in the Map, which is one more than needed (or 2 if new java 8 methods are used). You should get the value and check it for null and keep a reference to the newly created Set instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm having trouble following your code. Does the "connection.get(key).add(val);" command add the integer 3 to the map, or the HashSet containing the integer 3?

Comment: @Ken Ill write an explanation in the answer. But `connection.get(key)` will return the `HashSet`. Then `.add(val)` adds the value to the set